# DataGridTemplateColumn ComboBox Binding and editing

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Brand Code">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Path=BrandCode, Mode=OneWayToSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Brands}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

the above code displays the list but when i select the value it doesn't assign back to BrandCode.

but if i click on the next column to edit the value is assigned to BrandCode,

can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=BrandCode, 
    Mode=OneWayToSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Brands}"/>
```

It depends what is in your items, but if your items are instances of a class and you want to return a particular property value, you could also try this:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=BrandCode, 
    Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedValuePath="NameOfPropertyToReturn" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Brands}"/>
```

I've just tested that definitely works... if it doesn't work for you, you have a problem lying elsewhere in your code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Brands}" SelectedItem="{Binding BrandCode}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue}" />
</StackPanel>
```

UPDATE >>>

After seeing your latest code for your data class, I can see your problem... how have you been able to write any WPF without learning about the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? The two go hand in hand. Your solution is to implement this interface in your `Data` class. Please see the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) page at MDSN for help with this.

Please note that *if* you had shown us all your code in the first place, we could have fixed this problem *immediately*.

Comment: hi i have  List<string> which is  "Brands" and a string BrandCode where i need the return value to be in. each item in the datagrid column comes from a list of object which contain Brands and BrandCode. the above recommendation doesn't work

Comment: That's strange... the first example *should* work... what do the error(s) in the Output Window say?

Comment: i know right?, no error when i try to access BrandCode, it returns null :-(

Comment: let me give you my `code`class public class Data {
 public List<BrandTable> Brands { get; set; } // contains brand names
 public string BrandCode { get; set; }  / should allow a user to select or enter one if it is not in the list
} `code` still doesn't work

Comment: also users should be able to change the existing brand

Comment: Dude!! Don't put code into comments... it *never* comes out right... add it onto the end of your question.

Comment: i do have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented (i didn't include that in the code above)

Comment: From the information that you've provided, I can't help you any further. You have a problem somewhere, but you haven't provided any code that contains the error, so there's nothing more that I can do for you at this point.